# how to set app icon badge by reading data from XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

i know XML parsing well. but having trouble in where to parse an above xml file.

```
<alertinformation>
<alertdetails>
<newflag>2</newflag>
</alertdetails>
</alertinformation>
```

I have to parse this xml file and display this value `<newflag>2</newflag>` in app icon badge. 
Now my doubt is, did this XMl fle parsing should be done in appDelegate? or in view controller.
Else guide where this xml file to be parsed and display the value

Answer (score 0):

For such a small xml file it basically doesn't matter where you do it, it's more depending on how your app looks like and where you normally would put that kind of logic.

Just implement a method somewhere, which returns an integer value for your xml-file, i.e.:

```
- (NSInteger)badgeNumberFromXmlData:(NSData *)xmlData {
    // Parse XML and return badge number
}
```

Then perform the actual parse operation and update the badge number:

```
NSInteger badgeNubmer = [someClass badgeNumberFromXmlData:xmlData];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeNumber];
```